# TREND function in Gnumeric only outputs one cell

Tags: trendlines, gnumeric

Hello I have a col of x values, and col of y values, and next to them an empty column, i am attempting to select the empty column of similar length as x and y, and enter the TREND function, but i only get an output in one cell.  How does one properly enter the TREND function?  I am using array Ctrl Shift Enter but it doesn't fill it out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the TREND function is supposed to establish the linear regression line's y value for the given x values. As such it's supposed to output an ARRAY. it's only outputting one cell.